# How to find the first word of a sentence for only three different options

Tags: java, regex

I can have these three kind of Strings

```
ALPHA_whatever_1234567

BETA_whateverDifferent_7654321

GAMMA_anotherOption_1237654
```

I want to extract from the Strings the beginning of them, whether is ALPHA, BETA or GAMMA.

So, for example, I would like to get:

```
ALPHA_whatever_1234567 -> ALPHA

BETA_whateverDifferent_7654321 -> BETA

GAMMA_anotherOption_1237654 -> GAMMA
```

I want to use Regular Expression, and I tried something like this

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(.*)_.*");
```

But it doesn't work for some Strings. I recover the beginning by

```
Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(string);
m.find(1);
```

I also tried this Pattern:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("([ALPHA]|[BETA]|[GAMMA])_.*");
```

But it returns only the first character of the String.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: don't you want to use split ??

Comment: Use the `find()` method, not `find(n)`.  All you're doing is telling it to start searching at position #1 instead of at the beginning of the string.  Also, you should always check the return value of `find()`; that's how you know if the match was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the brackets around the `ALPHA`, `BETA` and `GAMMA` since they represent character classes, i.e. `[ALPHA]` will match either of the letters A, L, P, H or A.

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(ALPHA|BETA|GAMMA)_.*");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex does not work because dot `.` consumes too much, eating up the underscore. Here is how you can fix it:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("([^_]*)_.*");
```

Another alternative would be to use a "reluctant" qualifier for the asterisk, but that may lead to [*catastrophic backtracking*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Your other solution uses character classes `[]` incorrectly. The correct expression would have no square brackets, like this:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(ALPHA|BETA|GAMMA)_.*");
```

Answer (score 1):

`[...]` in regex is a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). A character class can only match a single character.

So `[ALPHA]` really means "match one of these characters: A, L, P, H, A"

If you remove the brackets, then it will match the entire word:

```
(ALPHA|BETA|GAMMA)_.*
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not insistent on using regular expressions, you could give this a try:

```
String firstWord = myString.split("_")[0];
```

Where `myString` contains your String.

Answer (score 0):

```
String strr = "ALPHA_whatever_1234567";
String[] result = strr.split("_");
return result[0];
```